# How can I remove the .php extension from my PHP page?

Tags: php, html, url, file-extension

I'm trying to remove the extension from my PHP page.

For an example, `www.mywebsite.com/verification.php`

I want people be able to verify from `www.mywebsite.com/verification`.

My code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
!DOCTYPE html
html lang="en"
head>

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: read about apache rewrite module and rewrite rules

Comment: use your .htaccess file

Comment: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php <- a tool that will make an htacess file for you

Comment: There's no indication on the question that the OP is using apache or has mod_rewrite enabled, therefore all comments and answers are basically jumping the gun a bit. So would the OP please enlighten us whether they use apache or something else?

Comment: Added an answer that does not use HTACCESS files

Comment: But it is not even valid HTML. E.g., both HTML tags `html` and `head` are incomplete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this website](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/):

Change your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You can do something similar, with the `.html` extension, except you change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If you don't have a `.htaccess` file, do what @Cagy79 said:

> You could make a directory `/verification/` and put your script in an `index.php`.
>
> In this way a user can go to `www.yoursite/verification/` without the need of adding the index.php part

Comment: I don't have .htaccess file

Comment: Answer is edited @LalitaTana

Comment: but i don't want to put it inside  a directory.

Comment: What can you do, we can't really help you if you just 'don't want' to do something.

Comment: I want it to be, http://mywebiste.com/verfiction it's not about i "don't want to do"

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the user would type in the same url, and it would go to the same place, since a directory would enable usage of `www.yoursite/verification/`

Comment: You are including MY answer as a quote in yours? That is hilarious! :

Comment: Yes, because @LalitaTana is not willing to listen to either one of us ;P

Comment: @LalitaTana we are not being 'jerks', and I apologize on the behalf of me and Cagy79, (mostly me) if that was implied, but you have to go with one of the solutions. If you don't tell us the setup of your project, then how can we help you? The two solutions me and Cagy79 showed you both worked, but you have to be willing to give some effort on your own part, because we _are not a code writing service_.

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried to implement both of your solutions, cagy79's solution is working, but is there any way i could create .htacess file manually?

Comment: @LalitaTana read [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-easily-create-and-edit-htaccess-file-for-your-site/)

Comment: thank you sir! both of you.

Comment: @LalitaTana You are welcome

Answer (score 4):

You could make a directory `/verification/` and put your script in an index.php.

In this way a user can go to `www.mywebsite.com/verification/` without the need of adding the `index.php` part.

(Also, this can be done when you can't edit .htaccess files or when not on Apache)

Comment: what are the reasons i don't have htaccess file?

Comment: You can create an .htaccess file in any directory on an Apache web server to configure specific settings for that directory. On some shared PHP internet providers you cannot access nor edit these files. With my solution you don't need .htaccess files at all.

Comment: It's a private VPs, i tried to create .htaccess file, it's not doing anything. :(

Comment: Are you using Windows to create the .htaccess file? because you can't on Windows.

Comment: nano htaccess (LINUX CENTOS), inside my /var/www/html/ folder, I know that "."htacess the dot means only for hidden files, therefore i created htacess (but i tried them both anyways :P )

Comment: double c in htaccess

Comment: lol yeah. i mean, i spelled it right :)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally you can use these two options mentioned in the [PHP manual security section](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php)

1. You can set `expose_php` to `off` in your php.ini file. Then no information about running PHP on your server will be sent in the header.
2. You can use a `.htaccess` file option to obscure the filename. Available options that are mentioned are:

Make PHP code look like other code types

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .py .pl
```

Make PHP code look like unknown types

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .bop .foo .133t
```

Make all PHP code look like HTML

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

The last method is not recommended, because all HTML files will run through the PHP interpreter, even if this is not necessary.

Comment: Could you explain something from the link? Link only answers are not recommended, since links may break

Comment: No need to downvote, I need some time to overhaul the answer...